# Выяснить, является ли ввод пользователя числом

Tags: python, массивы, условия

```
x = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
y = input()
```

есть список, содержащий все цифры. Человек вводит что-то, нужно узнать, является ли это что-то числом

Comment: А массив при чём? Можно проверить на наличие элемента в массиве с помощью in, но не факт, что это хорошая идея

Comment: Проверку на число можно сделать через isdigit

Comment: @modeller isdigit не работает на отрицательных числах и на числах с точкой/запятой

Comment: @MBo, я думал седлать так, чтобы каждый элемент переменной сверялся с каждым элементом массива, и если каждый элемент переменной совпадает с каким-либо элементом массива(т.е. каждый эл. перем. - цифра, а значит переменная - число), то это число

Comment: Для некоторых случаев такой посимвольный разбор требуется, но здесь нужно просто попробовать перевести в число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, а именно: проверить является введенные пользователем данные числом, то можно сделать так:

```
try:
    int(input())
    print('Это число')
except ValueError:
    print('Это не число')
```

Если имелось ввиду что-то другое, то уточните вопрос :)

Comment: а если это _нецелое_ число?